# A positive supermartingale is closed on the right

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis

I would like some help with proving the following statement:

Let $(X_t)_{t \in I}$ be a positive $(F_t)_{t \in I}$-supermartingale, that is, $E[X_t |F_s] \leq X_s$ for all $s \leq t$. Then $(X_t)_{t \in I}$ is closed on the right, that is, there exists some integrable random variable $k$ such that $E[k|F_t] \leq X_t$ for all $t \in I$.

I have tried with the variable $k = \inf_{t \in I}(X_t)$ but couldn't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A basic convergence theorem says that $(X_t)$ converges a.s. and Fatou's Lemma finishes the proof. Without knowing how much of Martinagle Theory you know it is not possible to answer the question.

Comment: Just take $k=0$.

Answer (score 0):

First we show convergence assuming $E[X_{0}]<\infty$. The $Y_{t}=-X_{t}\leq 0$ is a submartingale that is bounded above by zero and so it is uniformly bounded in $L^{1}$

$$\sup_{t}E[|Y_{t}|]=\sup_{t}(-E[Y_{t}])\leq (-E[Y_{0}])=E[X_{0}]$$

and so by Doob's submartingale convergence, $X_{t}\to X_{+\infty}\in L^{1}$.

We claim that in OP $k:=X_{+\infty}$. By [conditional Fatou lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Fatou%27s_lemma_for_conditional_expectations) and submartingale, we have

$$E[X_{\infty}\mid\mathcal F_n]=E(\liminf_{t\to +\infty} X_{n+t}\mid\mathcal F_n)\leq \liminf_{t\to +\infty} E(X_{n+t}\mid\mathcal F_n)\leq X_{n}.$$